# undefined method `each' for main:Object (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby

[image]

I'm trying to run this file in my console but when I run it I get this error: undefined method `each' for main:Object (NoMethodError)

I'm trying to take the word that was typed in by using `self`, then loop through it checking to see if its letters have a matching value in my hash then print the array back to me containing all the values in that word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self` can't get any values, maybe you are looking for something like `gets`:

```
def scrabble
  values = {"a" => 1, "e" => 1, "i" => 1, "o" => 1, "u" => 1}

  list = []

  gets.chomp.split("").each do |letter|
    list << values[letter]
  end

  puts list
end
```

`gets` will ask user for input (in console) and with `split` you convert that input into an array with all characters, then you can use `each` that array.

Answer (score 1):

The keyword `self` refers to the current object. [This post](https://www.jimmycuadra.com/posts/self-in-ruby/) might give you some info.

To record some input and iterate it:

```
# codes...
input_string = gets.chomp
input_string.each_char do |letter|
  # codes....
end
```

Comment: I actually tried doing that input = gets.chomp then input.each() but I got this error undefined method `each' for "a":String (NoMethodError) however i didn't add _char and when i added that it worked! thanks